# Deserialization throws StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, serialization

How do I properly do deserialization? Throws StreamCorruptedException(: invalid type code: AC) for line `Movie movie = (Movie) ois.readObject();`.

```
static void loadMovieFromDataBase(List<Movie> list) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("movies.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        while(fis.available() > 0) {
            Movie movie = (Movie) ois.readObject();
            list.add(movie);
        }

        ois.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Serialization:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("movies.ser", true));
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.close();
```

Comment: Typically you'd need to also examine the serialization code to understand why deserialization has failed.

Comment: Don't use `available()`. It doesn't do what you think it does. Seems that your `movies.ser` file is corrupted. Did you write it correctly?

Comment: I wrote below. My directory with files. [link](https://zapodaj.net/0ba9bcfeb5b83.png.html)

Comment: You can't append to an object output stream file, at least not without extra precautions that you aren't taking.